# With it the play?

Tags: extraposition

> This introduction is taking forever. I wish they'd just get on with it the play.

I just came across this sentence on this link [Merriam Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20on%20with%20(something%20or%20someone))

But is that sentence grammatically correct? 
I mean "it" can be used in that way? **"it"** seems indicating **"the play"** in the same way as in **"I found it hard to explain the problem"** (Here, **"it"** is indicating **"to explain the problem**"

I've never heard **"the + word"** can be indicated by **"it"**.
If it's possible, could you make some sentences as well?
I think it'd be just an error.

Comment: @Lambie then, is that sentence okay if "a comma" is added right before "the play"? as in "with it, the play".  If okay, is "the play" the appositive of "it" ?

Comment: No, you either use a noun or it. You don't add a noun after it. No,  no comma, no apposition. Not in speech.  It is ***extremely*** unlikely.

Comment: @Lambie I fully understand it!

Comment: Great. Now I shall go for my walk before I kick the bucket staring at this stupid screen .)

Comment: @Lambie - I wish you’d just get on with your walk! (Or, _I wish you’d just get on with it!_, but, as you say, not, _I wish  you’d just get on with it your walk_.) P.S. I’m upvoting the question because the OP found what appears to be an error in a reputable dictionary. Nice work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so:

It's some kind of punctuation error or misplaced word. Play should not be there, or be there without the it. "get on with it" or "get on with the play". NOT both. :) –

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As was explained in the comments already, the sentence should read either:

> This introduction is taking forever. I wish they'd just get on with the play.

Or:

> This introduction is taking forever. I wish they'd just get on with it.

The one instance I can think of where one might use both is when the words “the play” were put in brackets to show that they were not part of an original quote, but they clarify a pronoun or other vague term within the quote:

> This introduction is taking forever. I wish they'd just get on with it [the play].

As [one writing website](https://writingcommons.org/open-text/research-methods-methodologies/integrate-evidence/incorporate-evidence/453-inserting-or-altering-words-in-a-direct-quotation) explains:

> When writers insert or alter words in a direct quotation, square brackets — [ ] — are placed around the change. The brackets, always used in pairs, enclose words intended to clarify meaning, provide a brief explanation, or to help integrate the quote into the writer’s sentence.

The website further explains using this example:

> It [driving] imposes a heavy procedural workload on cognition
>
> Note: Brackets are placed around the inserted word in this example to let the reader know that ‘driving’ clarifies the meaning of the pronoun ‘it.’